# unable to find element

Tags: selenium, java

I have the following code

```
    //import java.io.IOException;

    //import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    //import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    //import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    //import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    //import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Big_Basket {

        public static void main(String []args){

             WebDriver driver;


                    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    driver.get("http:\\www.google.com");

                    System.out.println("The webpage name is :"+ driver.getTitle());

                    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Big Basket");
                    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/span/h3/a")).click();
                    System.out.println("The webpage name is :"+ driver.getTitle()); 

                    driver.get("http://bigbasket.com/");
                    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("ftv-city-selectboxdiv"));
                    Select se=new Select(element);
                    se.selectByVisibleText("Bangalore");

                    driver.findElement(By.id("area_selection")).clear();
                    WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.id("area_selection"));
                    Select se1=new Select(element1);
                    se1.selectByVisibleText("Jayanagar 4 Block, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("area_selection")).sendKeys("Jayanagar 4 Block, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("area_selection")).equals("Jayanagar 4 Block, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India");
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("#set_visitor_address")).click();

                    driver.findElement(By.id("id_q")).clear();
                    driver.findElement(By.id("id_q")).sendKeys("Apples");
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='auto_search']/div/form/input[2]")).click();

                    driver.close();
                    driver.quit();  
    }
        }
```

**The error occurring is**

```
The webpage name is :Google
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/span/h3/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'shaheena-PC', ip: '192.168.0.10', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=42.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: bc42f0ec-5a72-4787-8f1b-b585a36de4a0
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/span/h3/a}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
    at Big_Basket.main(Big_Basket.java:29)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/span/h3/a"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'shaheena-PC', ip: '192.168.0.10', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous518124023766071695webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous518124023766071695webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous518124023766071695webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous518124023766071695webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/shaheena/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous518124023766071695webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

I used all locators type to find element again i'm getting same error

Comment: After search Big Basket in google , where you are trying to click using that xpath?

Comment: Quick look tells me the xpath is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

You are using incorrect xpath syntax to click on link , Correct code is :

```
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");

            driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Big Basket");

            driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/span/h3/a")).click();
```

I have removed .(dot) from your xpath and it is working.

Comment: Quick and easy solution, but sometimes hard to find such issues :)

Comment: @Dhiman - Yes you are right..